# how can i fix database acces issues in firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an Android Java app that reads and writes to the Firebase Realtime Database.

Everything works fine on my home network (where I first ran this project). However, on any other network (and I've tried a few), I cannot log in.

Here are the solutions I've attempted:

- I used anonymous login, which allowed me to log in, but then I couldn't read the database.
- I also tried changing the rules, but with no success.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Here is my login activity (works on home networks, but not on other networks)

```
package com.example.firebaseproj;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener
{
    Button btnLogin , btnFastLogin , btnRegistraion,btnLogOut,btnExit,btnAnonymous;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    EditText etUserName,etPassword;
    TextView tvMsg;
    String userName,password;
    User user1;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        firebaseAuth  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnonymous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnonymous);
        btnAnonymous.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFastLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFastLogin);
        btnFastLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRegistraion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnRegistraion.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnLogOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogOut);
        btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMsgs);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (view == btnFastLogin)
        {
            fastLogIn();
        }
        if (view == btnAnonymous)
        {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(this, dbMongo.class);
            signInAnonymously();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (view == btnLogin)
        {
            // data check
            if (!etUserName.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !etPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {

                user1 = new User(etUserName.getText().toString(),etPassword.getText().toString());
                logIn(etUserName.getText().toString(),etPassword.getText().toString());

            }
            else {
                tvMsg.setText("bad data");
            }
        }
        if (view == btnRegistraion) {
            // data check
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registration.class);
            resultLauncher.launch(intent);
        }
        if (view == btnLogOut) {
            if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance() != null )
            {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                tvMsg.setText("user sign out");
            }
            else
                tvMsg.setText("no user");
            // app closing
        }

        if (view == btnExit)
        {
            logOut();
            finish();
        }
    }
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> resultLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                    result -> {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                            if (result.getData() != null) {
                                user1 = (User)result.getData().getSerializableExtra("user");
                                tvMsg.setText(user1.getUserName()+" " + user1.getPass());
                                registerUser();
                            }
                        } else if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Result canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            tvMsg.setText("cancel by user");
                        }
                    });
    private void registerUser() {
        String email = user1.getUserName();
        String password = user1.getPass();

        // Check if email and password are not empty
        if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Create a new user with email and password
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Registration successful
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // You can add further actions like navigating to the main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("user",user1);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            // If registration fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    public void fastLogIn()
    {
        logIn("dany123@gmail.com","dany123");

    }
    public void logOut()
    {
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null )
        {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            tvMsg.setText("user sign out");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User logout ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            tvMsg.setText("no user");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void logIn(String email,String password)
    {
        //logOut();
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            String name = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            User user3 = new User(name);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("user",user3);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                Exception e = task.getException();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("Authentication failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });




    }

    private void signInAnonymously() {
        firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d("Auth", "signInAnonymously:success");
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                // Update UI or proceed with user being signed in
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w("Auth", "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: "I cannot log in" it's hard to help with. What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect.